# Adding freeform PRO to expression engine

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have had a website built for me using EE and am now needing to add a plugin. I free form lite installed and put in the license key for freeform PRO but cannot access CRM area. (keeps saying to upgrade).

Do I upload the plugin add-on to the general website files for PRO?

I see only a limited view in the back office (I guess the way the CMS was built). and nowhere specific to upload the PRO plugin. Any help would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to download from Solspace and then upload on your server in your addons folder. I guess there's more infos on Solspace doc/website how to upgrade.

And it looks like you not logged as super admin in the CP.. maybe you won't able to install/update to pro

Answer (score 0):

Once you purchase an upgrade from Lite to Pro, you receive access to a new set of Freeform files that include both the Lite and Pro features in the download package. You'll need to download the Freeform Pro package from your Solspace account, then replace the current files with the new files on your server. The license key in itself does not enable/activate any Pro features. :)